# What is the meaning of «residência permanente»?

Tags: português-brasileiro, vocabulário

Would you use the term "residência permanente" to refer to the address of stay only or also to a legal permission to be in a foreign country?

For example in Germany the permanent residency address is "dauerhafter Wohnsitz", while the permission to stay is "Niederlassungserlaubnis".

hypothesis: the permission is maybe "visto permanente" or "autorização de estabelecimento", "residência permanente" could be the address I think.

Thank you.

Comment: You are right, the permission is ["autorização/visto de residência permanete"](http://www.imigrante.pt/PagesPT/DocumentosNecessarios/ConcessaoAR/21Art80.aspx)

Comment: address: domicílio in legal texts.

Comment: http://www.tjdft.jus.br/institucional/imprensa/direito-facil/residencia-e-domicilio

Answer (score 3):

**"endereço de residência permanente" means your home address.** If you live in Germany and travel to Brazil but intend to go back home (i.e. there is no immigration involved) it means **your address in Germany**, even if you are staying here for six months or a year.

A foreigner can enter Brazil under one the following **types of visa**:

> - Visto Diplomático
> - Visto Oficial
> - Visto de Cortesia
> - Visto de Turista
> - Visto de Trânsito
> - Vistos Temporários
> - Vistos Permanentes
> - Visto de Residência Temporária

If you aren't talking about visa of any kind, we have the following terms in pt-BR:

- **"endereço residencial"** - This is current usage when a Brazilian asks another Brazilian his home address. If you come to live in Brazil for a period of time you will be asked your "endereço residencial" meaning the address you are staying while you're here.
- **"endereço de residência permanente"** - A Brazilian may be asked that when they are abroad, or at a hotel here in Brazil.  Likewise, a foreign tourist may be asked that in Brazil.
- **"endereço do estabelecimento"** - That's not about a home, but about a firm address (an office, a commercial unit, a factory, etc)
- **"endereço comercial"** or **"endereço do trabalho"** - here the asker wants to know where your workplace is located.